# Connect Power BI gateway to Company Network Drive/Drive

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am new to `Power BI`. I have created some reports which gets data from network drive of my company. Everything works fine as long as I do things on Power BI Desktop on my system.

But when I try to update report on `Power BI` service, I am not able to connect to refresh reports.

I don't have understanding of how to connect Gateway data source to Network drive/folder. I have installed Gateway on my system.

Also I tried connecting to Folder Data source in gateway, below is the error I am getting.

> Unable to connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect to .
>   Details: "We could not register this data source for any gateway instances within this cluster.
>   Please find more details below about specific errors for each gateway instance."Show details
>   Troubleshoot connection problems

I am passing my login credentials in the data source settings.

Kindly guide the exact way to connect to configure gateway or data source so that I can refresh reports through shared drive as data source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed Datagateway correctly, is it running? Installing a gateway does not immediately turn it on.

Here is what my gateway is one and running:
[image: data gateway on and running]

If you don't see a green tick, etc. then you may need to Sign in, and Configure the gateway. For me there was minimal to no custom configuration required, I just needed to log in to my domain.

The button to do this will be on the same screen that I showed in my screenshot. There will be a blue button. Click it and follow the prompts.

I also needed to do a restore on the gateway, for whatever reason, but this was as simple as putting in the recovery key that I created in installation. You may not need to do this step.